# What's the best way to insert data from dbfpy into MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, dbf

I'm using the [dbfpy module](http://dbfpy.sourceforge.net/) to read data from DBF files with the intention of writing that same data to equivalent MySQL tables. Here's a rough version of my code:

```
###################
# BEGIN CONFIG 
###################

import_root = '/Users/shawn/Dropbox/ITistic Inc/Digital Aspire/Clients/MVP/Automated Sales Report Project/pdq dbf export 1.30.2013'
concept_id = 1

###################
# END CONFIG 
###################


import os
import datetime
from dbfpy import dbf
import MySQLdb


# Connect to MySQL
db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'dbposireporting', 'posi', 'dbposireporting')
cur = db.cursor()


discount = dbf.Dbf(os.path.join(path, 'DISCOUNT.DBF'))

for rec in discount:
    print rec['date']
    print

    # LINE BELOW NOT WORKING:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO discount VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", rec)

discount.close()

db.close()
```

The MySQL table I'm trying to insert into contains one additional field which I need to populate with the concept_id value set at the top of the script. That value is not part of the DBF records (rec). What's the best way for me to insert this data?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could replace `rec` in the `cur.execute()` line with

`tuple(rec) + (concept_id,)`

Oh, and don't forget to add one more `%s` for it.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the fields are strings, you'll need to wrap them in quotes for the SQL to be valid.